# std::cin>> is digit or string

Tags: c++, cin, stdstring, typechecking

I have to determine if the input is a digit or a string.

```
std::string s;
while (std::cin >> s) { 
    if(isdigit(s)){
        //do something with the variable
    }
    else{
        //do something else with the variable
    }
}
```

For this I get
`error: no matching function for call to 'isdigit(std::__cxx11::string&)'`
Could someone propose a method I should use?

Comment: there's `std::isdigit()`, but it doesn't take string; it takes character.

Comment: Or use std::stoi and if it succeeds it was a number, but that requires exception handling. But it can handle negative numbers too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`isdigit()` works on a single character (and indicates if it is a numerical value between `'0'` and `'9'`). To check to see if you have a single digit:

```cpp
std::string s;
while (std::cin >> s) { 
    if(s.size() == 1 && isdigit(s[0])){
        //do something with the variable
    }
    else{
        //do something else with the variable
    }
}
```

To check to see if all characters are digits...

```cpp
std::string s;
while (std::cin >> s) { 
    bool alldigits = true;
    for(auto c : s) {
       alldigits = alldigits && isdigit(c);
    }

    if(alldigits){
        //do something with the variable
    }
    else{
        //do something else with the variable
    }
}
```

Comment: Could also use `std::all_of` instead of a loop in the second case.

Comment: could you please write an example for `std::all_of` ?

Comment: @kaycaborr You need a new header file `#include <algorithm>`. Then the test becomes a one liner `if (std::all_of(s.begin(), s.end(), isdigit))`.

Comment: @john, actually, it is not wise to pass `char` values to `isdigit()` directly. See the warning in [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit). So, at the very least, it should be this instead: `if (std::all_of(s.begin(), s.end(), [](unsigned char ch){ return isdigit(ch); }))`

Comment: @robthebloke that applies to your examples too, eg you would need `isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(s[0]))` and `isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(c))` instead.  Or, in the case of the `range-for` loop: `for(unsigned char c : s)`